# Laravel - Undefined variable: articles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
public function press (Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('search')){
        $articles =  Press::search($request->input('search'))->get();
    }
    return view('pages.press.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

I'm receiving an error `Undefined variable: articles`. Above is the code I'm using in my controller. What is the error that I'm making?

VIew

```
 @if(!empty($articles))
    @foreach ($articles as $article)
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box border">
          <div class="box-header">
            <a href="{{ url('/press/'.$article->slug) }}"><img src="{{ url('http://assets.hobohweb.com/uploads/press/'.$article->image) }}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <a href="{{ url('/press/'.$article->slug) }}"><h6 class="h-2x">{{ $article->title }}</h6></a>
            {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->created_at)->diffForHumans() }} on <a href="{{ url($article->source_url) }}" class="text-primary">{{ $article->source }}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  @endif
```

Comment: Please try to location return statement inside if block and also make else block to processing if there isn't 'search' key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if there are any articles in your search, like:

```
if($request->has('search')){
    $articles =  Press::search($request->input('search'))->get();
} else {
    $articles = [];
}
```

And use it in the view:

```
@forelse($articles as $article)
    ...
@empty
    <p>There are no articles!</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Bingo. This is what i was looking for with forelse. One last question, i followed this https://medium.com/@samogorm/basic-search-functionality-with-elasticsearch-laravel-scout-6ac182c99cbf now the search works well. How should i know if the search is from elasticsearch. I do not see any difference

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable inside the `if`, but if the condition is false, the variable is never set. Try to use an `else` condition:

```
public function press (Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('search')){
        $articles =  Press::search($request->input('search'))->get();
    } else {
        $articles = null;
    }

    return view('pages.press.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

You will also need to check if `$articles` is null in your view.

Comment: if i use nulle it give me Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\FINAL\hobohweb\resources\views\pages\press\index.blade.php)

Comment: you need to check whether variable is null or not in your blade template file.

Comment: You need to check for null in your view. Or, you need to create another condition to get articles without using search. For null result, you can show a message to the user, for example.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I got that to work. I removed the pagination links. How to paginate the results?

Answer (score 0):

that's because the variable is never assigned a value and does not exist in the external context of the -if

try to use this

```
public function press (Request $request)
{
  $articles = array();

   if($request->has('search')){
       $articles =  Press::search($request->input('search'))->get();
   }

   return view('pages.press.index', [
     'articles' => $articles
   ]);
}
```

View

```
   @foreach ($articles as $article)
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box border">
         <div class="box-header">
           <a href="{{ url('/press/'.$article->slug) }}"><img src="{{ url('http://assets.hobohweb.com/uploads/press/'.$article->image) }}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
         </div>
         <div class="box-body">
           <a href="{{ url('/press/'.$article->slug) }}"><h6 class="h-2x">{{ $article->title }}</h6></a>
           {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->created_at)->diffForHumans() }} on <a href="{{ url($article->source_url) }}" class="text-primary">{{ $article->source }}</a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   @endforeach
```

I hope this help you

Comment: How to paginate the results?